# Windows Phone 7 External Communication

Tags: windows-phone-7, bluetooth, external-accessory

From what I've read online in forums and blogs, Windows Phone 7 has no support for bluetooth serial. There also does not seem to be any support for communication with accessories through USB. Can someone give me a definitive answer as to whether or not Windows Phone 7 can do any sort of command and control for external accessories? I've used bluetooth serial on Android as well as the iOS external accessory framework. I would imagine there would be some level of support for external accessory communication in the Windows Phone 7 platform.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that there is no Bluetooth/External Accessory API exposed as part of the SDK. There may be a private API available to select parties (though I'm not familiar with any apps that do so), so it might be worth contacting Microsoft.

Keep in mind that, even if you find a private/internal API you won't be able to call it (even via reflection) and it would be caught during the certification process anyway.

If it's not possible to communicate with the accessory via Sockets/HTTP then I'm afraid you're out of luck for now.

Comment: I agree with @Richard . I still feel they should provide support for using private APIs.. Development would be more fun.

Comment: @Anil - They can provide support for private APIs by making them public. If private APIs are supported, then there is no such thing as an unsupported API and they may as well do away with public/private.